# Remove all characters except for certain characters and numbers

Tags: r, regex, string

I'm working with string vector and I want to remove all characters except for certain characters `C_Keep` and any set of numbers succeeding these letters.

```
C_Keep <- c("ab", "acr", "sb", "scr")
```

For example, take the following string in a data frame:

```
text <- "ab 187; acr 76 98 298 876 987; legislature governors office attorney generals office re gaming issues ab 1416 165 187 267; calepa support sb 265; scr 17689 986 83783 3982"

df <- data.frame(text)
```

I would like the output to populate into a be

```
"ab 187; acr 76 98 298 876 987; ab 1416 165 187 267; sb 265; scr 17689 986 83783 3982"
```

If it could also be in a column in the data frame `df` that would be great. Such that the final results look like the object in `df`:

```
text <- "ab 187; acr 76 98 298 876 987; legislature governors office attorney generals office re gaming issues ab 1416 165 187 267; calepa support sb 265; scr 17689 986 83783 3982") 

output <- "ab 187; acr 76 98 298 876 987; ab 1416 165 187 267; sb 265; scr 17689 986 83783 3982"

df <- data.frame(text, output)
df
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse` (`stringr`) solution. Please carefully test it on more strings to ensure that it behaves as expected on your data.

Setup:

```
library(tidyverse)
C_Keep <- c("ab", "acr", "sb", "scr")
text <- "ab 187; acr 76 98 298 876 987; legislature governors office attorney generals office re gaming issues ab 1416 165 187 267; calepa support sb 265; scr 17689 986 83783 3982"
```

Solution:

```
# This regex checks for any of the strings in C_Keep
keep_regex = paste(C_Keep, collapse = "|")
text %>%
  # Split into separate strings to work with one at a time
  str_split("; ") %>%
  unlist() %>%
  # Grab only the text following anything in C_Keep
  map_chr(
    str_extract, 
    # The pattern is (keep_regex), followed by numbers (or spaces) 
    # i.e., [0-9| ]+
    pattern = paste0("(", keep_regex, ")", "[0-9| ]+")
  ) %>%
  # Put it all back together into a single string
  paste(collapse = "; ")

#> "ab 187; acr 76 98 298 876 987; ab 1416 165 187 267; sb 265; scr 17689 986 83783 3982"
```

**Update**: Data frame solution

To perform this action on a set of strings that might be in a data frame, we first need to put our work into a function.

For simplicity, I'm first going to make the function only work with one string at a time. There are other ways to do this, but I don't want to make significant changes from my original work above.

```
# Let's make the function accept a vector of "keep_strings" as 
# a parameter in case the strings change in the future. I'm
# calling it extract_info_helper because it is only able to work
# with one string at a time. 
extract_info_helper = function(text, keep_strings) {
  # Our function will only work with one string at a time,
  # so let's check that at the start to ensure it is not misused
  stopifnot(length(text) == 1)
  
  # This regex checks for any of the strings in keep_strings
  keep_regex = paste(keep_strings, collapse = "|")
  
  # Output:
  text %>%
    # Split into separate strings to work with one at a time
    str_split("; ") %>%
    unlist() %>%
    # First grab only the text following anything in C_Keep
    map_chr(
      str_extract, 
      # The pattern is (keep_regex), followed by numbers (or spaces) 
      # i.e., [0-9| ]+
      pattern = paste0("(", keep_regex, ")", "[0-9| ]+")
    ) %>%
    # Put it all back together into a single string
    paste(collapse = "; ") 
}
```

Now we will make a function that accepts a vector of texts, and calls `extract_info_helper()` on each of them. I will use `map_chr()` to do this (`map_chr()` helps us call a function on each element of a vector, and the `_chr` means that the output will be a character vector).

```
# This one will work with a vector of texts by calling 
# extract_info_helper() on each of them, one at a time.
extract_info = function(texts, keep_string) {
  map_chr(
    texts, 
    extract_info_helper, 
    keep_string = keep_string
  )
}
```

Now we are ready to work within a data frame. I'll make an example data frame so that you can see how it can work.

```
data = tibble(
  text = c(
    "ab 123; acr 12 34 56", 
    "example ab 567",
    "eg sb 7537 9842; hi ab 384; sb 894257"
  )
)

# A tibble: 3 x 1
  text                                 
  <chr>                                
1 ab 123; acr 12 34 56                 
2 example ab 567                       
3 eg sb 7537 9842; hi ab 384; sb 894257
```

Now here's how you would call the function:

```
data %>%
  mutate(output = extract_info(text, keep_string = C_Keep))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  text                                  output                         
  <chr>                                 <chr>                          
1 ab 123; acr 12 34 56                  ab 123; acr 12 34 56           
2 example ab 567                        ab 567                         
3 eg sb 7537 9842; hi ab 384; sb 894257 sb 7537 9842; ab 384; sb 894257
```

Comment: This one works remarkably well! Thank you! Anyway, that it can paste the output into its correct columns? That is if the strings are in a data frame, the code makes a new column that it inputs the strings into?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with regards to pasting output into correct columns. If you'd like to edit your question to show what these columns might look like and how you want it to work, I can update this answer accordingly :)

Comment: Awesome, Thank you so much for your help. You are a real life saver. I updated the question to reflect the desired data format. I hope it is clear enough.

Comment: This is an amazing answer! Thank you so much for taking the time to write it out and for all your help. I really appreciate it!